# Как использовать функции с переменным числом параметров?

Tags: c, функции

Вот есть такая программа (вырезал ненужное)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
#define Documents "Odin", "Dva", "Tree", "Chetire"

void func(int (int document_count, ...) {
    char *p = &document_count; //??
    while (document_count--) {
        printf("%s", *p);
        p++;
    }
    
}


int main() {
const char *p[4] = {Documents};
printf("%s", p[0]);
printf("%s", p[1]);
printf("%s", p[2]);
    func(4, Documents);
    return 0;
}
```

Мне нужно вывести как строки 4 слова из define. Как это делается? В мейне получается,  но как реализовать в функции?

Comment: Да что там, что-то поменялось при оформлении вопросов? Что все последние вопросы идут с кодом, как будто это JS? :(

Comment: @Harry новички путаются в иконках/оформлении, вряд ли тут что-то большее замешано )

Comment: @Kromster Но сегодня — это что-то особенного... Подряд...

Comment: @harry ТерВер не против локальных флуктуаций =)

Answer (score 4):

Почитать, как работают функции с произвольным количеством аргументов. Только учесть, что некоторые авторы пытаются это делать через указатели — так вот таких надо ни в коем случае не слушать. Если они не используют `va_list` — отправлять их назад в школу...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

#define Documents "Odin", "Dva", "Tree", "Chetire"

void func(int document_count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,document_count);
    while (document_count--)
    {
        char * p = va_arg(ap,char*);
        printf("%s\n", p);
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main()
{
    func(4, Documents);
}
```